# Blender-GIS Get SRTM python error

Tags: add-on, error

I'm running Blender 3.4.1, and I am following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mj7Z1P2hUWk&list=LL&index=3) to generate a 3D map.

The Basemap function works fine.

I got a valid API key from OpenTopography but when I try to get the elevation data (either through the option "OpenTopography SRTM 30m" or "OpenTopography SRTM 90m" I get an error message including:

'URL can't contain control characters':

[image]

Does anyone know waht's wrong??
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Since that's an external addon not included in Blender, you should report the error to the author, but it doesn't appear to have been updated since May 2021 (v2.28) and there are various recent error reports on the [github issues page](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues) for it

Answer (score 0):

I had to go back to Blender 2.9 to get it to work.